# passing id to next activity through bundle

Tags: android

All i tried is to pass the listview selected items id to the next activity and show the id in a `TextView` on another page. I receive a number format exception when i click on list item. Any suggestions please.

> DataBaseWrapper is the class where database is created.

**DishOperation**

```
  public class DishOperation {

    // Database fields
    private DataBaseWrapper dbHelper;
    private String[] DISHES_TABLE_COLUMNS = { DataBaseWrapper.DISHES_ID, DataBaseWrapper.DISHES_NAME,DataBaseWrapper.DISHES_INGREDIENTS };

    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DishOperation(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DataBaseWrapper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close()
    {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public Dish addDishes(String name,String ingredients) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(DataBaseWrapper.DISHES_NAME, name);
        values.put(DataBaseWrapper.DISHES_INGREDIENTS, ingredients);


        long dishId = database.insert(DataBaseWrapper.DISHES, null, values);

        // now that the student is created return it ...
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBaseWrapper.DISHES,
                DISHES_TABLE_COLUMNS, DataBaseWrapper.DISHES_ID + " = "

                        + dishId, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();


        Dish newComment = parseDishes(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return newComment;
    }

    public void deleteDishes(Dish comment) {
        long id = comment.getId();
        System.out.println("Comment deleted with id: " + id);
        database.delete(DataBaseWrapper.DISHES, DataBaseWrapper.DISHES_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }

    public List getAllDishes() {
        List dishes = new ArrayList();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBaseWrapper.DISHES,
                DISHES_TABLE_COLUMNS, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Dish dish = parseDishes(cursor);
            dishes.add(dish);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
        return dishes;
    }

    public String getInformation(Dish i)
    {
        long id=i.getId();
       String ing= i.getIngredients();
        return ing;

    }


    private Dish parseDishes(Cursor cursor) {
        Dish dish = new Dish();
        dish .setId((cursor.getInt(0)));
        dish .setName(cursor.getString(1));
        dish .setIngredients(cursor.getString(2));

        return dish ;
    }
}
```

**Activity 1**

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button   btListe;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dishDBoperation = new DishOperation(this);
    dishDBoperation.open();

 final List values = dishDBoperation.getAllDishes();
 final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
 setListAdapter(adapter);
 ListView listView = getListView();
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
      intent.putExtra("key",id);
      startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**Activity 2**

```
int value;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
            long value = extras.getLong("key");
        text.setText(String.valueOf(value));// updated!!


        }


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
value =Integer.parseInt( extras.getString("key"));
```

with

```
 long value = extras.getLong("key");
```

also in your Activity2 you should move

```
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.result);
```

in the very beginning of `onCreate` otherwise your `findViewById` will return null.

Edit.

Accordingly to the code you posted you have an `ArrayAdapter` of `Dish`. Your `dataset` and your `ArrayAdapter` should reflect it, and this can be done with `Generics`.

To get the `id` of your row as argument of `onItemClick`, you have to override `getItemId`. E.g.

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Dish>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values ) {
      @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
         return getItem(position).getId();
      }
 }));
```

Comment: Your answer some how helped me! can u please tell how to display this in my textview?

Comment: try with `text.setText(String.valueOf(value));`

Comment: that looks good. Isn't working ? Can you print the value on `onItemClick` using the Log ?

Comment: When i debug the following line. On each item clicked it gives the id as 1. Why it is not giving id from the sqlite database table.

Comment: that's a different issue. What's is values? What kind of objects does it contain?

Comment: i want my value variable value to be the id of clicked list item driven from data table.

Comment: you have to subclass the adapter and override getItemId and let it return the table's id. Why aren't you using one of the CursorAdapter ?

Comment: you still need to subclass ArrayAdapter   and override getItemId

Comment: if you can help me with editing your answer. i will be grateful to you

Comment: I'll do it, but I need to know what `getAllDishes();` is returning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96050/discussion-between-tabia-and-blackbelt).

Comment: Thankyou for this :) but i want to display the id of clicked item on `Activity_2` within  a text view not in a list

Comment: and to do so, you have to change your Adapter as  I did in my edit.

Comment: And for so! does i need to make a new function in DishOperation file?

Comment: no you don't. You just need to change the `setListAdapter ` call in your Activity

Answer (score 0):

In Activity 1, id is of type `long` and in Activity 2, you try to retrieve it as a `String`. 
Retrieve it by `extras.getLong("key");`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `value = extras.getLong("key"));`